# How to move elements from one list to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I want to move elements from one list (A) to another list (B). 
The problem is that i want to sort the elements of the list A, and I'm using the list.js library, witch is very good.

Here you can see how everything works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Danny182/yzeupzrt/15/

The problem is that if I use an option to sort the list A the elements that i moved on list B goes back to list A. 
 You can see it from the fiddle!

This is the code I'm using to move elements from one list to the other:

```
$('.add').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    $("li#p-"+ id + "").detach().appendTo('#your-team');
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Your `jsFiddle` is not very intuitive. How to test that? What's being expected?

Comment: maybe now it's a little better! @MelanciaUK

Comment: what do you want to sort listA by? what does list.js do for you?

Comment: maybe I shouldn't use the function "detach" (to move elements from one list to the other) because the elements that will compare in the list B don't need the "ADD TO LIST B" button.

Comment: @mcG73 You can use the **search bar**. The **buttons** _"role"_, _"name"_ _"value"_, _"team"_ and the **Select** witch shows only the right _team_

Comment: `.appendTo()` would be enough I believe.

Comment: @MelanciaUK here you can see it gives me the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Danny182/yzeupzrt/16/

Comment: Problem is your List.js, nothing else. It seems, list.js has already constructed the html for the list, and everytime u select something in the dropdown it populated all the items. I am not very familiar with list.js, but if u are, then i guess there must be some api they would have provided to update the list. Try that.

Comment: no, I'm not very familiar with the library, do you know another library that let's me sort the list in the same way? with instant research? @Prashant19sep

Comment: Hey, it just works fine on my machine, but dont know whats wrong with you fiddle. Wait I put the code you can try

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('.add').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    //$('#your-team').append($("li#p-"+ id + "").html());
    $("li#p-"+ id + "").detach().appendTo('#your-team'); 

    //$("li#p-"+ id + "").remove();
    userList = new List('players', options);
    //userList = new List('players', options);
})
```

Comment: Just declare your variable "userList" globally.

Comment: thank you, but it's not working. trying it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/Danny182/yzeupzrt/24/

Answer (score 0):

```
var userList;
$(document).ready(function(){
//FUNCTION TO SORT THE LIST A. 
    var options = {
        valueNames: ['teame', 'role', 'name', 'value', 'team' ]
    };

    userList = new List('players', options);

    $('#teams').change(function () {
        var selection = this.value; 
        console.log (selection);
        if (selection == "tutte") {
            userList.filter();
            return false;
        }
        userList.filter(function(item) {

        if (item.values().team == selection) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
    //THIS FUNCTION DETACHES THE ELEMENTS FROM LIST A AND IT APPENDS IT TO THE LIST B
    $('.add').click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        //$('#your-team').append($("li#p-"+ id + "").html());
        $("li#p-"+ id + "").detach().appendTo('#your-team'); 
        //$("li#p-"+ id + "").remove();
        userList = new List('players', options);
        //userList = new List('players', options);
    }) 
});
```

Comment: in this way they don't go back to list A, but they always disappear from list B

Comment: WAit for sometime I will let u know.

Comment: what do u mean by "working only for select". Also, pls confirm if this is exactly your html, or this is modified by your list.js also. If you can post the original html that you have may be i can help u with this.

Comment: i'm getting the elements from a MySQL database. it's similar but not the same. here's the link of my HTML: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43867401/insert-rosa%20copy.php
css is missing, and I don't think you can access to the page. 
I edited my list.js time ago for the list limit of a number of elements. 

only for the **select** i mean that it works  for filtering the players for team 1 or team 2 or team 3! but not for the sorting buttons or the search.

Comment: sorry here's the HTML: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43867401/insert-rosa.php

Comment: it would be complicated. that list.js had even the instant research :(

Comment: Above fiddle is only for moving the players in between the lists. No Sorting. You can do sorting using the link above.

Comment: If you are so interested to use that list.js, then atleast go thru its documentation. know what you are using. know the apis they have exposed.

Comment: Thank you for the help you are giving me. I will need the code you wrote to move elements from one list to the other! The problem is that I even need the sorting of the list because i have like 300 players. I tried to read the API from the main site, but they aren't well explained. There is a **update()** function witch i don't know how to use. I could even use the **remove()** function to delete elements from the list, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I'm still trying to do this, but it doesn't work. do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Prashant10sep I'm still trying to use the lib _list.js_ but when i move items the if I sort the list A they disappear from list B. here I tried even the function _remove()_ but it seems to don't work.  You can see it using the _console.log_ http://jsfiddle.net/Danny182/yzeupzrt/31/

Comment: Will let u know if i find something on this.